# How to make a single Fortran array encompass two pointer arrays?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, mpi, shared-memory

Fortran code:
Trying to make use of MPI shared memory windows, I don't have much experience with fortran pointers.

**Requirement:**
I would like to do is have multiple (two or more) processors allocate shared memory, but map these locations onto a single array **A**, 
For example, if making an array of 100, have 2 allocated memory

**Here is the code:**

```
N=10
!allocate shared memory window
if(shmrank<2)then !allocate all memory on proc 1 and 2
 winsize=8_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND*N*(N/2)
else
 winsize=0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
end if
!Begin shared memory window
call mpi_win_allocate_shared(winsize,1,MPI_INFO_NULL,shmcomm,baseptr,win,ierr)
```

I can then get the size and pointer location using the shared_query, where ***baseptr0*** refers to the memory allocated by **processor 0**

```
call MPI_Win_shared_query(win,0,winsize,disp_unit,baseptr0,ierr)
 !  write(6+rank,*)'post shared_query',shmrank,winsize0
call MPI_Win_shared_query(win,1,winsize,disp_unit,baseptr1,ierr)
 !  write(6+rank,*)'post shared_query',shmrank,winsize1
```

To allocate all the memory on a single processor, I simply do the following,

```
!associate Fortran pointer with shared memory
  call C_F_POINTER(baseptr, A, arrayshape)
```

and I can now access A(1:100).

If possible, I would like to access A so that, for example, A(1) starts at baseptr0 and A(50) starts at baseptr1.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to do this? or an alternative that wouldn't require too many changes to the rest of the code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A full code illustrating the requirements would be so much clearer. But as stands and if I understand you I don't think you can portably. But if it's OK to allocate 1 100 element block and the generate 3 Fortran pointers, one to all of it, one to the first half of it and one to the second half of it, well that's fairly easy.

Comment: Hi Ian. The issue is that when I'm using these shared memory arrays, if I allocate the whole array on one process, it limits the amount to a fraction of the total nodes memory. 
If I can split up the allocations among different cores on a node, I can use the total available memory. But accessing different arrays for different sections would be a lot messier to implement.

Comment: Why do you think you are limited if you alloc on one process?

Comment: I assumed the memory per processor was split by MPI. So I thought a 24 core node with 64 GB of memory would assign 2.6 GB to each. But I don't think that's the case anymore because I've allocated about 47GB now.

Comment: Indeed. There's no magic splitting, the memory is available to all the processes until it is used up, there's absolutely no requirement that it be equally split.